# How to calculate quiz answer number?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a quiz with 6 questions and 3 possible results. After each right answer, the user sums 1 point. After each wrong one, zero points. So, in this case, the maximum amount of points is 6 and the minimum is zero.

These 3 results are like 'congratulations, you are awesome' and 'booo, you suck'.

Thinking about that:

```
Points      Answer
0           1
1           1
2           1 or 2?
3           2
4           2 or 3?
5           3
6           3
```

What is the calculation that's going to say which of the answers the user sees? If I change the number of questions, que calc remains? And answers number?

I need this count to return me a integer (to match an index on a json file).

This is my current javascript —with no success.

```
const feedback = (quiz, score) => {
    const numberFeedback = quiz.feedback.length; // now 3
    const numberQuestion = quiz.questions.length; // now 6
    const fConstant = numberQuestion / numberFeedback;
    const percentage = score / numberQuestion;

    // the consoles below are my tries and errors on calculations. All wrong.
    console.log((score * fConstant) / numberFeedback);
    console.log(Math.round((score * fConstant) / (numberFeedback - 1)) - 1);
    console.log(Math.round(percentage * fConstant));
    console.log(percentage * fConstant);
};
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to calculate?

Comment: here's my guess on what you're trying to do, please confirm: you want a function that will run at the completion of the user's quiz, which has inputs of Total # of questions and Score, and will output one of the three possible results?

Comment: `1 + int (0.5 + score / numberQuestions * (numberFeedback - 1))` should do the trick